# Adding Date to text field in SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have this code I am adding to a textbox, a cell in a grid to be exact.

```
=Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -1, Now()), "yyyy")
```

What I want to do is change the "Now()" portion to a parameter that I am asking from the user

```
=Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -1, Parameters!Year.Value, "yyyy")
```

However this is not working.

So my question is how do I get a year date from the user then subtract 1 year from that and display it in one of these text fields?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides you have a missing bracket, try converting to date type the parameter value.

```
=Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Year, -1, DATESERIAL(CINT(Parameters!Year.Value),1,1)), "yyyy")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I didn't even notice the missing bracket! However neither worked. What I get is an #Error in the text field. Thank you for your input!

Comment: What type is your parameter? Is It date or text? is it multivalue? is it nulleable?

Comment: So your user input a date or a year?

Comment: If the user is just inputting a year, you could try `CInt(Parameters!Year.Value) - 1`.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. What I'm gathering is that I needed the Dateserial and CINT part.